# Resolve different versions of dependencies in Android Studio (gradle)

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, vungle-ads

I integrates two libraries to my android project: Vungle SDK and Tune SDK. So, Tune SDK has `de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0` dependency, but Vungle has a `eventbus-2.2.1.jar`. If I add both of them to project, I give an error: `Multiple dex files define` error. But if I don't add one of version of eventbus to project, I give `NoDefClassFoundException` runtime.

So, how to resolve this? This is very painful

Comment: Why not use "Option 1. Including the Vungle SDK as an AAR via Maven" as seen [here](https://support.vungle.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000468071)?

Comment: I use 4.1.0 version for integration with AdMob Mediation. This version hasn't .aar package. Also, I don't khow about compatibility 5.1.0 version with AdMob Mediation.